# How to take advantage of additional data?

Tags: deep-learning

I am trying to train a 3 class problem object detection problem,For these 3 classes i have around 9000 samples each.The model is performing decently but there is still confusion between classes.

I have additional data for these classes but this data is NOT annotated, i only have the images, i could probably annotate them for what class they belong to, but annotating bounding boxes will not be possible.

is there something i can do to take advantage of this data that i have?may be some pretraining or something, im not really sure.

Any suggestions will be helpful.Thanks in advance.